# onMouseOver in React element selecting all elements rather than just single

Tags: reactjs

I've setup a component which onMouseOver display a 'div' which states what the component is, as it's a link.

However, when you hover over any single one of the elements, it displays all of the 'divs' instead of just the appropriate one to hover.

I know this is because my function 'generally' sets the state, and if said state is true it displays all - but I don't know how to refactor my code to select only the relevant one.

Here's my code:

```
class SideNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = {
      linkHover: false
    }
    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);

  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    this.setState({
      linkHover: true
    });
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({
      linkHover: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <section className="side-nav-section">
        <div className="side-nav-container">

          <div className="side-nav-links-container">
            <div className="side-nav-link" link="new-debt" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
              { this.state.linkHover ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Link a debt</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }
            </div>


            <div className="side-nav-link" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
              { this.state.linkHover ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Dashboard</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }
            </div>


            <div className="side-nav-link" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
              { this.state.linkHover ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Analytics</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }

            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I feel like I should know this, it seems like a straightforward problem but can't figure it out.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach here would be using an `Int` to identify the element. Then you pass it as param to `onMouseEnter`. `onMouseLeave` just sets it to `false`, so nothing is being displayed.

```
this.state = {
  linkHover: false
}

onMouseEnter(id) {
  this.setState({
    linkHover: id
  });
}

onMouseLeave() {
  this.setState({
    linkHover: false
  })
}

<div className="side-nav-link" link="new-debt" onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnter(0)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
   { this.state.linkHover == 0 ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Link a debt</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }
</div>

<div className="side-nav-link" onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnter(1)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
   { this.state.linkHover == 1 ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Dashboard</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }
</div>

<div className="side-nav-link" onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnter(2)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
  { this.state.linkHover == 2 ? <div className="side-nav-link-hover"> <p className="side-nav-link-hover-paragraph">Analytics</p> <span className="side-nav-link-span"></span> </div> : null }
</div>
```

As soon as you are familiar with the class components of React, I would advise you to have a look at the newer funtional components with hooks. They produce a much more readable code!

Comment: Thank you - that works. Appreciate the response. All of my code is structured as components over hooks for now, but plan to refactor in the future.

Comment: There is no need to refactor it. Class components will be supported in the future as of now. You can just start writing your new components with hooks, as soon as you feel ready. There is no issue other than maybe aesthetics in mixing class and functional components. ;)